# Como modificar a porta do Glassfish sem iniciá-lo?

Tags: glassfish

Estou precisando modificar a porta do Glassfish no servidor sem iniciá-lo, pois, acabei instalando um outro serviço que está fazendo uso da porta 8080 e não posso pará-lo para iniciar o Glassfish e ir até o painel de administração para alterar. Tem algum jeito de fazer isso nos arquivos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, há como modificar através de arquivos. Vá a pasta do Glassfish e acesse as seguintes subpastas:

```
PASTAGLASSFISH/glassfish/domains/domain1/config
```

Dentro dessa pasta config há um arquivo chamado `domain.xml`. Edite nele a seguinte parte:

```
<network-listener protocol="http-listener-1" port="8080" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp"></network-listener>
```

Coloque em port="SUAPORTA" a porta que você deseja, como 9999:

```
<network-listener protocol="http-listener-1" port="9999" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp"></network-listener>
```

Agora basta iniciar o Glassfish normalmente.